# Operate a task on all word files in a folder and all sub folders VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am fairly new to this site and this is my first post.  Here we go: 
I am writing a fairly simple code on VBA that replace a certain chain of character by nothing.  I have that part figured out, however I would like to operate that code on all the files in a big folder containing sub folder on and on.... I saw a similar question asked on here before, but it does not work for me since i'm trying to put in a "**If**" in the code to verify the file is a word file and if it is then it calls the operation ( secondSubRoutine ) who does the required task on the file. If someone could tell me why it's not capable to find the word files, it would be really helpful!

Aurelion.

```
Sub domino()

Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String

HostFolder = "C:\CLIENTS"

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub
Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files

        If File.Name = "*.docx" Then

             Documents.Open FileName:=File

             Call secondSubRoutine

             ActiveDocument.Save
             ActiveDocument.Close

        ElseIf File.Name = "*.doc" Then


            Documents.Open FileName:=path & File

            Call secondSubRoutine

            ActiveDocument.Save
            ActiveDocument.Close

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: [Recursively enumerate folders and files](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/990/scripting-filesystemobject/10411/recursively-enumerate-folders-and-files#t=20170706200346311142) using FSO, on Documentation.SO.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
For Each File In Folder.Files
    If Right(File.Name, 5) = ".docx" Or Right(File.Name, 4) = ".doc" Then

         Documents.Open FileName:=File.Path

         Call secondSubRoutine

         With ActiveDocument
            .Save
            .Close
        End With
    End If
Next
```